# Unable to find column with logical name: product

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate throws error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: 
    Unable to find column with logical name: product in 
        org.hibernate.mapping.Table(product_part) 
    and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_part")
public class ProductPart implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "product", nullable = false)
    private ProductPart productByProduct;

    @ManyToOne
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "part", referencedColumnName = "part", nullable = false)
    private Part partByPart;
    }
```

**MySQL table**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_part` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `part` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_product` (`product`),
  KEY `fk_part` (`part`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product` FOREIGN KEY (`product`) REFERENCES `product` (`product`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_part` FOREIGN KEY (`part`) REFERENCES `part` (`part`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

What is the problem? How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

Linked tables by foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE `part` (
      `part` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`part`)
    )
```

**and**

```
    CREATE TABLE `product` (
      `product` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`product`)
)
```

Comment: Solved by replacing `private ProductPart productByProduct;` with `private Product product;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your class have

```
@ManyToOne
@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "product", nullable = false)
private ProductPart productByProduct;
```

This is Hibernate Self Join Annotations. Have @ManyToOne but don't have @OneToMany. Table not define the 'product' column.
You need add

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="productByProduct")
private Set<ProductPart > subProductPart  = new HashSet<ProductPart>();
```